# unable to get sorted-map-by and apply work together

Tags: clojure

I am having trouble using a custom comparator with sorted-map-by and apply. How do I make the expression below work -

```
(apply sorted-map-by > {1 "ab" 3 "cs" 2 "vs"})
```

I get the below exception -

> IllegalArgumentException No value supplied for key: [3 "cs"] 
>   clojure.lang.PersistentTreeMap.create (PersistentTreeMap.java:87)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are wanting to sort on keys with an existing map, you could use `into`:

```
(into (sorted-map-by >) {1 "ab" 3 "cs" 2 "vs"})
```

This works because `(sorted-map-by >)` returns an empty sorted map, so using functions like `into` and `assoc` will work as expected while the map maintains the sorted order.

```
;=> {3 "cs", 2 "vs", 1 "ab"}
```

The `sorted-map-by` function works on flat arguments:

```
(sorted-map-by > 1 "ab" 3 "cs" 2 "vs")
;=> {3 "cs", 2 "vs", 1 "ab"}
```

Applying it to this map would give an odd number of pairs:

```
(apply list {1 "ab" 3 "cs" 2 "vs"})
;=> ([1 "ab"] [2 "vs"] [3 "cs"])
```

And it is trying to make every other one a value to a preceding key, hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

You would use `apply`, if the number of arguments to pass to the function is not known at compile-time. So the best way is to use

```
(into (sorted-map-by >) {1 "ab" 3 "cs" 2 "vs"})
```

Comment: You use apply when the arguments are supplied via a collection. The fact that the number of arguments is not known at compile time is intrinsic to that.